# eof error when trying to initiate commands in python ftp_tls module

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, server, ftp, tls1.2

I have bought two servers both being from the same hosting company and same package,
the first server bought works perfectly, this was just for testing and experimental,
the other server which I have been told by support team that their ssl and ftp versions are the same
does not work and gives me an error in my python script when trying to initiate commands.

```
'''

from ftplib_custom import FTP_TLS
import ssl
import ftplib_custom
import socket

def launch():
#Wait upon user input
print("Press Enter To Initialise Server Connection: ")
input()

#Info
print("Server Found")
print("Admin Auto Login...")
print("\n")

#Connection Initiation

#Working Test Server
ftp = FTP_TLS('MyHostname', user='Username', passwd='Password')

#Not Working Server
ftp = FTP_TLS('MyHostname', user='Username', passwd='Password')

ftp.ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS

print(ftp.getwelcome())
ftp.set_debuglevel(1)
ftp.set_pasv(True)
ftp.prot_p()
ftp.ccc()

print ("Login Successful")

def listLineCallback(line):
    msg = ("** %s*"%line)
    print(msg)

#Commands
ftp.pwd()
ftp.cwd("/")
ftp.retrlines('LIST', listLineCallback)
#ftp.dir()

launch()
'''
```

This is what I get from the working test server...

```
'''
Press Enter To Initialise Server Connection: 

Server Found
Admin Auto Login...


220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 10:53. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
*cmd* 'PBSZ 0'
*resp* '200 PBSZ=0'
*cmd* 'PROT P'
*resp* '200 Data protection level set to "private"'
*cmd* 'CCC'
*resp* '200 Control connection unencrypted'
Login Successful
*cmd* 'PWD'
*resp* '257 "/" is your current location'
*cmd* 'CWD /'
*resp* '250 OK. Current directory is /'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*resp* '200 TYPE is now ASCII'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (91,103,219,222,232,11)'
*cmd* 'LIST'
*resp* '150 Accepted data connection'
** drwxr-xr-x    2 sensitive   sensitive         4096 Dec 18 15:53 .*
** drwxr-xr-x    2 sensitive   sensitive         4096 Dec 18 15:53 ..*
** -rw-------    1 sensitive   sensitive            4 Oct 28 15:59 .ftpquota*
*resp* '226-Options: -a -l \n226 3 matches total'
'''
```

This is what I get if I try and connect to the main server...

```
'''
Server Found
Admin Auto Login...


220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 10:57. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
*cmd* 'PBSZ 0'
*resp* '200 PBSZ=0'
*cmd* 'PROT P'
*resp* '200 Data protection level set to "private"'
*cmd* 'CCC'
*resp* '200 Control connection unencrypted'
Login Successful
*cmd* 'PWD'
*resp* '257 "/" is your current location'
*cmd* 'CWD /'
*resp* '250 OK. Current directory is /'
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*resp* '200 TYPE is now ASCII'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (91,146,105,202,253,214)'
*cmd* 'LIST'
*resp* '150 Accepted data connection'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\install\Desktop\WebsiteConnecting\Website_FTP_Testing.py", line 54, in <module>
    launch()
  File "C:\Users\install\Desktop\WebsiteConnecting\Website_FTP_Testing.py", line 51, in launch
    ftp.retrlines('LIST', listLineCallback)
  File "C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib_custom.py", line 488, in retrlines
    return self.voidresp()
  File "C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib_custom.py", line 251, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib_custom.py", line 236, in getresp
    resp = self.getmultiline()
  File "C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib_custom.py", line 222, in getmultiline
    line = self.getline()
  File "C:\Users\install\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib_custom.py", line 210, in getline
    raise EOFError
EOFError
'''
```

Any help would be much appreciated and I will edit or add upon request for whats needed.

```
'''
EDIT:
Status:     Resolving address of ########
Status: Connecting to 91.146.105.202:21...
Status: Connection established, initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted".
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Selected port usually in use by a different protocol.
Status: Resolving address of ######
Status: Connecting to 91.146.105.202:21...
Status: Connection established, initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted".
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of #######
Status: Connecting to 91.146.105.202:21...
Status: Connection established, initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted".
Error:  Could not connect to server
'''
```

Comment: Can you retrieve the directory listing using any FTPS client running on the same machine as your Python code? – If you can, show us its log file.

Comment: Yes I can connect with Filezilla however it doesn't work if I configure it to connect implicitly over tls, I will update post now whereas explicitly over tls I am able to connect to the server fine

Comment: I have asked you for a log file of a successful connection. What you have posted does not look like a successful connection. And it's not a log file either. It looks like a copy of the message log from FileZilla GUI, which is not useful for any debugging.